# Maximo formula that uses a custom formula function/automation script?

Tags: formula, maximo

In Maximo 7.6.1.1:

I would like to create an attribute formula that uses a custom formula function/automation script.

---

I've tried doing it with the steps below, but unfortunately, I get an error when I try to use it in WO Tracking:

```
BMXAA3761E - The event has failed. Ensure that the event is registered correctly.
See the log file in the APP HOME directory for more details about the error.
null
```

---

Steps:

1. Create an automation script:
   [image]
2. Add/Modify Formula Function:
   [image]
3. Add/Modify Formula For Attribute:
   [image]
4. Create a WO. Save it so that the attribute formula is invoked.
5. Error:

[image]

From the SystemOut log:

```
Caused by: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.tivoli.maximo.expression.FormulaMboEventListener.preSaveEventAction(FormulaMboEventListener.java:213)
    at psdi.server.event.EventTopic$Subscription.preSaveEventAction(EventTopic.java:731)
    at psdi.server.event.EventTopic.preSaveEventAction(EventTopic.java:342)
```

---

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error?

Related question here: [Can Maximo formulas return null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59447159/can-maximo-formulas-return-null)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what problem are you trying to solve. If you're just trying to play around with formula, I don't have much experience with it, but from what I understand, it can only return a number. So returning null is not possible. (Although there is a SETVALUENULL function which can be used to set a different field to null, but the function itself returns 0 and 1).

If the purpose is to return the X, Y coordinate value to Work Order from Asset/Location/Service Address, and setting it to null when there is no value, how about we still using standard formula and let it returns a 0 when everything is null. Then, we create a separate attribute launchpoint script on "validate" event of the ERI attribute, check to see if the value is 0, then we will overwrite it with a null using this code:

```
    if mbo.getDouble("eri") == 0:
      mbo.setValueNull("eri")
```

Comment: This could be a good workaround but I'd refrain from modifying data within the `validate` event. I'd use the `action` event instead.

Comment: @JPTremblay Are you aware of a safe way to get an automation script to fire ***after*** a formula?

Comment: I don't know. I would need to look at the Formula framework in details. Why would you want to do that? Formulas are specialized features and a subset of what an [attribute] automation script can accomplish. Basically, if you're not calculating a number, you should switch to an autoscript.

Comment: In this case, we can have an auto script that overwrite the 0 value with a null on the Work Order object's Save event. It will ensure the value is overwritten after the formula. Will it work for you?

Answer (score 2):

From what I see, this `preSaveEventAction` method is not expecting a `null` value and voluntarily crashes. Look at the `com.ibm.tivoli.maximo.expression.Expression.eval()` method from the Javadoc. It is returning a BigDecimal, a clue that a formula should return a number.

https://developer.ibm.com/static/site-id/155/maximodev/7609/maximocore/businessobjects/

So the reason you're getting this error seems to be because your script returns an invalid value, same as here: [Can Maximo formulas return null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59447159/can-maximo-formulas-return-null)